How to perform min, max, etc on table of text stored numbers?



Walmart.com
Target.com




=hyperlink("Link to product","$10.79")
=hyperlink("Link to product","$9.99")



How can I turn the text in each cell into it's numeric value, in the example table above, to run min() and max() on them?

Use VALUE built-in function.

MIN(INDEX(A2:B2*1)) and MAX(INDEX(A2:B2*1))

Use numeric labels, as in =hyperlink("Link to product", 10.79), and format the cell as Format > Number > Currency. The hyperlink cell will contain a number that can be directly aggregated with min() and max().

Nice one... again. :-)
